# Android Debug keystore

Tags: java, android, windows-7, android-keystore

I'm trying to access my .android debug.keystore so I can use it for facebook.

When I type into windows cmd: `C:\Users\<user>\.android\debug.keystore`

I get `C:\Users\<user>` is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file.

Can someone please tell me whats going ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In command line type

```
cd %USERPROFILE%/.android
```

You can find debug.keystore in this location

Comment: I have another issue when I put in keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
it says openssl is not recognized as internal or external command blah blah

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following a tutorial and they did not install openssl

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15520/discussion-between-eric-oboite-and-nandeesh)